# How to return a method value as list for RadHtmlChart ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, telerik

I'm using a `RadHtmlChart` based on HTML5 from telerik. I'm using a  Pie Chart, and I want to display the method's values. How should I save the values -- maybe as a list? It shouldn't have a big impact on the method itself, because I need this method for some report stuff.

```
public double GetBookedVacation(int year)
{
    int counter = 0;
    if (this.AnnualVacations.Any())
    {
        foreach (HtVacationDay vacationDay in HtVacationDays)
        {
            foreach (DateTime vacationDayDate in vacationDay.GetDates())
            {
                if (vacationDayDate.Year == year)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Thanks for help and fast answer.

Comment: How is the performance of your method related to the chart control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends on your needs, but a List seems the easiest option. The chart can take different datasources (start [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart/examples/databinding/bindtolist/defaultcs.aspx) and go through the section), or you can create the chart programmatically in each iteration of the loop by adding items and series through code. This may be harder to maintain, depending on your case. Also, since you return the counter how do you intend to give data to the chart without changing it (e.g. an out parameter)?

Comment: So fare so good but how can I recreate this method to give me back a list,? Cause I just want the value from this method to use it for the chart

Comment: One way would be using an out parameter, as I said: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: local variable named 'counter' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'counter', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: Well, take a look around the net on using such variables and implement it. Once again - this is dependent on your project and you are the only one who can fix it. If you can't - then post some relevant code so we can see what is wrong.